# How to check if roleArn obtained from customer's AWS account is a valid role and it exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How to check if roleArn obtained from customer's AWS account is a valid role and it exists. We are asking customer to create a cross account role and we would like to verify if the roleArn which they provided does exist

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: an arn is only created for aws resource when the resource is created, there can be situation that arn exist from beforel isn't that customer's job to check it out?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the IAM Role you have been given does not have permission to use IAM, the only way to know if the role exists would be to **try and use it!**

If it fails, you can look at the error message to see whether it was an **authentication failure** (eg credentials do not exist), a **permissions failure** (eg you are not allowed to do what you requested) or a **service error** (eg bucket doesn't exist).